# How to convert 1D array to 2D by column major

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

say I have a 1D array like `int[] x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}`.
I would like to conver it into 2D where it looks like:

```
1 5  9 13  
2 6 10 14  
3 7 11 15  
4 8 12 16
```

Currently, I have

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Nb; j++)
        s[i][j] = x[i + j];
}
```

However, that doesnt work. How would I do this?

Comment: That 2D array looks very random...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
for (int i = 0, k=0; i < 4; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < Nb; j++)
    s[j][i] = x[k++]; // you may want s[i][j]
```

Comment: thanks that works Also, why would I want s[i][j], that wouldnt work.

Comment: It depends on whether you consider the first look up to be the row or the column. Your examples has `s[i][j]` which could be valid depending on how you look at it.

Comment: what is Nb in your for loop?

Comment: @KickButtowski The same as in the original question.  I imagine it could be `4`.

Comment: is there any general case to solve this? can u provide me any tutorial so I can learn the logic?

Comment: @KickButtowski I would start with these tutorials http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ It includes using arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that stray `7` was a typo?

Since we want the inner loop to move downward, and the outer to move rightward, you can do this:

```
for i in (0..width)
   for j in (0..height)
      s[j][i] = x[i*height+j]
```

Tracing this out illustrates why it works:

```
s[0][0] = x[0*4+0] = x[0]
s[1][0] = x[0*4+1] = x[1]
...
s[0][1] = x[1*4+1] = x[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

No clue what `Nb` is, but you're way off on reading the initial array. Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        s[j][i] = x[i*4 + j];
```